# how i can assign the result of the entry textbox to a variable to then pass into a function in the backend?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

I'm having some issues programming a hangman game using tkinter, with the front-end and back-end separated AND both using OOP (i understand using OOP in the backend wasn't really necessary and it probably would've been better as a library but I'm doing this as a learning exercise) . I'm new to tkinter and i was wondering how i can assign the result of the entry textbox to a variable to then pass into a function in the backend. I was also wondering if my self.letter_row and self.guesses_left labels would then be updated as they are updated in the backend, and though i have assigned them to the front at the initiation of game_gui(), i'm not sure if they'll do this automatically. Here's all the frontend code...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import hangmanSkeleton as hm

class game_gui():

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Hangman")

        this_game = hm.Hangman()

        self.word = this_game.word
        self.letter_row = this_game.letter_row
        self.letters_guessed = this_game.letters_guessed
        self.guesses_left = this_game.guesses_left
        self.letter = StringVar()

        self.lbl_word = Label(master, text = "Welcome to Hangman!")
        self.lbl_word.grid(row = 0,padx = 10 , pady = 15, columnspan = 2)

        self.lbl_row = Label(master, text = self.letter_row)
        self.lbl_row.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.lbl_guesses = Label(master, text = "Guesses Left: " + str(self.guesses_left))
        self.lbl_guesses.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 15, pady = 10)

        self.entry_letter= Entry(master, textvariable = self.letter)
        self.entry_letter.grid(row = 2, padx = 10, pady = 20, columnspan = 2)

        self.guess_button = Button(master, text = "Guess Letter", command=lambda: this_game.guess_letter(self.letter))
        self.guess_button.grid(row = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10, columnspan = 2) 


root = Tk()
gui = game_gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And here's just the function from the backend that I'm trying to get to work in self.guess_button() above..

```
def guess_letter(self, letter): 
    try: 
        if type(letter) != str or len(letter) != 1 or letter not in ascii_lowercase:
            raise TypeError
        if letter in self.letters_guessed:
            raise ValueError
        elif letter in self.word:
            for count in range (len(self.word)):
                if letter==self.word[count]:
                    self.letter_row = self.letter_row[0:count] + letter + self.letter_row[count+1:]
        else:
            pass
        self.guesses_left = self.guesses_left-1 #take one away from guesses
    except TypeError:
        print("Value given is not a letter")
    except ValueError:
        print("Letter has already been guessed")
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: I still can't get my labels self.letter_row and self.guesses_left to update though

Yes, these variables are not bound to the `Label`, i recommend using `Label.configure(text=...` instead.
**Note**: I show only `.this_game.letter_row`!

Add a function `update_labels(...` and `.configure(...` the Labels text:

```
def update_labels(self):
    self.lbl_row.configure(text=self.this_game.letter_row)
    # and so on
```

Call this function at **last** in `.__init__(...` **and** `.guess_letter(...`.
The variable `self.letter_row` is not needed at all.

---

> **Question**: how i can assign the result of the entry textbox to a variable to then pass into a function in the backend.

Change the following:

- Make your variable `this_game` a member of `class game_gui`

  ```
  self.this_game = hm.Hangman()
  ```
- Add a helper method `guess_letter(...` to `class game_gui`.
  Pass the letter to `.this_game.guess_letter(...`.
  Clear the letter from `.letter`.

  ```
  def guess_letter(self, letter):
      self.this_game.guess_letter(letter.get())
      letter.set('')
  ```
- Change the `command`, pointing to the helper method:

  ```
  ..., command=lambda: self.guess_letter(self.letter)
  ```

Comment: brilliant! didn't know you could add this_game onto the object but that works so well. I still can't get my labels self.letter_row and self.guesses_left to update though - any advice on this?

Comment: also strangely its raising the 'value given is not a letter' error but not the repeat letter one, not sure whats going on there cos its all working in the backend...